# failed to execute script due to unhandled expection: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute 'main'

Tags: python

```
import tkinter as tk
import time
import os

# Cria a janela principal
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Desligamento Automático")

# Cria os campos de entrada para o dia, hora e minuto
day_label = tk.Label(root, text="Dia:")
day_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
day_entry = tk.Entry(root)
day_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)

hour_label = tk.Label(root, text="Hora:")
hour_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
hour_entry = tk.Entry(root)
hour_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

minute_label = tk.Label(root, text="Minuto:")
minute_label.grid(row=2, column=0)
minute_entry = tk.Entry(root)
minute_entry.grid(row=2, column=1)

# Cria o botão para confirmar o desligamento
def shutdown():
    # Obtém o dia, hora e minuto do desligamento
    day = int(day_entry.get())
    hour = int(hour_entry.get())
    minute = int(minute_entry.get())

    # Obtém o horário atual
    current_time = time.localtime()

    # Define o horário de desligamento
    shutdown_time = (current_time.tm_year, current_time.tm_mon, day, hour, minute, 0,
                     current_time.tm_wday, current_time.tm_yday, current_time.tm_isdst)

    # Calcula o tempo restante até o desligamento
    time_remaining = time.mktime(shutdown_time) - time.mktime(current_time)

    # Espera até o horário de desligamento
    time.sleep(time_remaining)

    # Desliga o computador
    os.system("shutdown /s /t 0")

# Cria o botão
shutdown_button = tk.Button(root, text="Desligar", command=shutdown)
shutdown_button.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=2)

# Executa a janela
root.main
```

What's wrong with my script? I'm trying to make a script that I can set a shutdown the hour/minute I want. I tried to make an executable, but I get this error everytime I try to execute it.

I get this message error everytime I run it.

Comment: Please write a [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is too much code in your question.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you didn't put brackets second, use `mainloop()`.

```
root.mainloop()
```